# Play framework: How to access a Plugin at runtime

Tags: scala, playframework

Let's assume the following Play plugin:

```
class MyPlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {

  def onStart = {
    ...
  }

  def onStop = {
    ...
  }

  def doThis = {
    ...
  }

  def doThat = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to invoke methods `doThis` and `doThat` from another class at runtime? My current solution consists of creating a companion object like this:

```
object MyPlugin {

  def doThis = {
    ...
  }

  def doThat = {
    ...
  }
}
```

... but since plugins are loaded by Play at application startup, is it possible to avoid the companion object?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the docs? "you can use it directly like app.plugin[MyPlugin].map(_.api.mymethod).getOrElse(throwMyerror)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Ryan's aswer:

```
app.plugin[MyPlugin].map(_.api.myMethod).getOrElse(throwMyError)"
```

Hope it helps.